# Migrate Cython driver to Rust FFI

Tags: rust, cython, symbols, ffi, lib

## Summary

I have some Cython code to interact with a 3rd party C++ driver library for a USB device. I am able to call the library from Python and open a device session. However, when I try to call the library from Rust using the FFI, I run into issues. Unfortunately, the 3rd party library is closed-source, so the best I can do is make sure my implementation is identical in Python and Rust.

## Working Python/Cython Implementation (Python 3.9)

```py
# main.py

from driver import Driver

def main():
    print(f"DriverVersion: {Driver.get_driver_version().decode()}")
    d = Driver()
    success = d.initialize_session()
    d.close_session()
    assert success

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# driver.pxd

from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "NrtControl.h":
    bool NrtOpenDevice( const char *cpPort, int *piSession )
    bool NrtCloseDevice( int iSession )
    const char * NrtGetDriverVersion()
```

```py
# driver.pyx

cdef class Driver:
    cdef int iSession
    cdef char *cpComport

    def __init__(self):
        self.iSession = 0

    def initialize_session(self):
        return NrtOpenDevice("COM8", &self.iSession)

    @staticmethod
    def get_driver_version():
        return NrtGetDriverVersion()

    def close_session(self):
        NrtCloseDevice(self.iSession)
```

```py
# setup.py

from distutils.core import Extension, setup

import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


def build():
    equipment_exts = [
        Extension(
            name="driver",
            sources=["driver.pyx"],
            include_dirs=[
                "C:\\Program Files\\NrtControl_for_Windows_20180921\\include",
            ],
            library_dirs=[
                "C:\\Program Files\\NrtControl_for_Windows_20180921\\VS2017\\x64\\Release"
            ],
            libraries=["NrtControl"],
            language="c++",
        )
    ]

    setup(
        cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
        ext_modules=cythonize(
            equipment_exts, compiler_directives={"language_level": 3}
        ),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    build()
```

I run the above with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and then `python .\main.py` and get the following output:

```
DriverVersion: 1.5.5.0
```

## Failing Rust Implementation (Rust 1.60)

```
// Cargo.toml

[package]
name = "nrt-ffi-bindings"
version = "0.1.0"
links = "NrtControl"
build = "build.rs"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
```

```rust
// build.rs

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=C:\\Program Files\\NrtControl_for_Windows_20180921\\VS2017\\x64\\Release");
}
```

```rust
// lib.rs

use libc::{c_char, c_int};

#[link(name = "NrtControl")]
extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "?NrtOpenDevice@@YA_NPEBDPEAH@Z"]
    pub fn NrtOpenDevice(cpPort: *const c_char, piSession: *mut c_int) -> bool;

    #[link_name = "?NrtCloseDevice@@YA_NH@Z"]
    pub fn NrtCloseDevice(iSession: c_int) -> bool;

    #[link_name = "?NrtGetDriverVersion@@YAPEBDXZ"]
    pub fn NrtGetDriverVersion() -> *const c_char;
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn open_close() {
        unsafe {
            println!(
                "DriverVersion: {}",
                CStr::from_ptr(NrtGetDriverVersion()).to_str().unwrap()
            );
            let port = CString::new("COM8").unwrap();
            let session: c_int = 0;
            let success = NrtOpenDevice(port.as_ptr(), session as *mut c_int);
            NrtCloseDevice(session);
            assert!(success);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above with `cargo test -- --test-threads=1`, I get the following:

```
DriverVersion: 1.5.5.0
thread 'tests::open_close' panicked at 'assertion failed: success', src\lib.rs:32:13
```

## Notes

`C:\\Program Files\\NrtControl_for_Windows_20180921\\VS2017\\x64\\Release` contains
`NrtControl.dll` and `NrtControl.lib`, which were provided to me by a 3rd party.

Without the `link_name` attributes above, I get errors at runtime about failing to resolve external symbols. I had to run `dumbin.exe` on `NrtControl.lib` and search for the proper symbol names to copy and paste. I tried to find a way to do this with `bindgen`, but eventually resorted to this manual process. If anyone knows how I can avoid this, please do share.

## Problem

So the problem is that my Rust invocation of the `NrtOpenDevice` function above returns `false` indicating failure, and I'm out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this.

## Edit 1:

Adding [NrtControl.h](https://pastebin.com/LYdpfYQw) and [nrtdef.h](https://pastebin.com/UuPwfBsx)

## Edit 2:

Following @rodrigo's suggestion below, I changed the call to:

```rust
let mut session: c_int = 0;
let success = NrtOpenDevice(port.as_ptr(), &mut session);
```

and it works (returns true)!

I still need to figure out how to make the link_name attributes target the correct symbol names automatically, as entering them manually is going to get tedious in the future...

Comment: Maybe you could post the contents of the `.h` file, that would be more useful than the python code. Also you can try with `extern "stdcall"` instead of `extern "C"`. Many C libraries do that. That said you could try using `bindgen` and getting that code automatically.

Comment: Also `session as *mut c_int` is wrong because `session` is not mutable. Write instead `let mut session: c_int = 0;` and then just `&mut session` without a cast.

Comment: Does `NrtOpenDevice` actually return a `bool`, or does it return some integer?

Comment: @rodrigo `&mut session` fixed it! Thanks! Do you have any idea why I have to specify the symbol names manually, when Cython seems to find them automatically?

Comment: Because they are not C functions but C++, with C++ decorated names but Rust FFI know nothing about that. As long as the ABI is C only, (`char*` instead of `std::string`) all should be well. I'm not sure but I think that if you use [`bindgen`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/cpp.html) you get that for free.

Comment: I did try using bindgen at first, but it didn't generate a link_name attribute at all (and failed to find the symbols at runtime). Maybe I should open up a separate issue for that...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make your question and title more general. As it stands it doesn't seem very useful for anyone but you. Maybe try to highlight the particular error message you're getting early on and in title.